# Count within a time period

Tags: sql-server

For a helpdesk application we have opened date, closed date, technician name.
Using sql server how can I create a query to show by month and over multiple years:

- how many jobs were closed for each month?
- for the last day of the month how many jobs were in the queue as unclosed, by technician name?
- average number of days to close a job by month by technician name?

Thanks

Comment: I would create the query using SSMS, but you can do it in any text editor.

Answer (score 0):

The query you require is a very simple SQL statement using the GROUP BY clause. Because you are asking information that needs grouping by date only and also information that needs grouping by date and by technician you should use GROUPING SETS.

```
select year(closed) as year
, month(closed) as month
, Technician
, count(*) as count
, avg(datediff(DAY,Opened, Closed)) as avgDays
from jobs
where not Closed is null

group by grouping sets
(
    (year(closed), month(Closed)),
    (year(closed), month(Closed), technician)
)
order by year(closed)
, month(closed)
, Technician
```

If you want the jobs that are not closed remove the NOT in the WHERE clause.

Comment: Thanks - but this doesn't give me the number of jobs that were open at the end of each month - so for January 2015 I need to know on the last day of that month how many jobs were not closed.  When I run the query (e.g. in December) old historical jobs from January will all hopefully be closed so removing the NOT in the WHERE clause won't help.  Does this need a sub-query?

Answer (score 0):

This is a partial answer using a helper table with the first day of every month in a date field.  This doesn't give by technician grouping but does calculate 'pending jobs'

```
select date, 
(select COUNT(1) FROM dbo.TASKS WHERE
OPENDATE<=date AND
(CLSDDATE>=date Or CLSDDATE is null))as 'Pending jobs',
(select COUNT(1) FROM dbo.TASKS WHERE
month(CLSDDATE)=MONTH(date) AND YEAR(clsddate)=YEAR(date)) as 'Completed jobs',
(select AVG(datediff(DAY,OPENDATE, CLSDDATE)) as avgDays FROM dbo.TASKS WHERE
month(CLSDDATE)=MONTH(date) AND YEAR(clsddate)=YEAR(date)) as 'AvgDays'
from dbo.CalendarMonths

where date<=GETDATE()
```